# Strange behavior in generating Numpy array with random values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

With this code I want to generate some small numbers in `Numpy` array format:

```
np.random.seed(1)
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((315,1))-1
```

this gives me result like this:

```
[[-0.16595599]
 [ 0.44064899]
 [-0.99977125]
 [-0.39533485]
 [ 0.70648822]
 [-0.81532281]
 [-0.62747958]
 [ 0.30887855]
 [-0.20646505]
 [ 0.07763347]
 [-0.16161097]
      .
      .
      .
```

But when i change rows count to 316 and upper:

```
np.random.seed(1)
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((316,1))-1
```

Then I get results in this number format(power notation):

```
[[ -1.65955991e-01]
 [  4.40648987e-01]
 [ -9.99771250e-01]
 [ -3.95334855e-01]
 [ -7.06488218e-01]
 [ -8.15322810e-01]
 [ -6.27479577e-01]
 [ -3.08878546e-01]
 [ -2.06465052e-01]
 [  7.76334680e-02]
 [ -1.61610971e-01]
 [  3.70439001e-01]
         .
         .
         .
```

I know this is power notation format but why this happens? I dont need this format.Why this strange behavior happens?

Comment: It's just an representation. Nothing within your array changes. Why this is happening? Probably because the spread of values is likely to increase when taking more samples and there is some threshold within numpy's print function. Of course you can tell numpy to print it as you like. Consider reading the docs for this.

Comment: @sascha: but how i can see real values(in non-power format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print a particular array without scientific notation using [`numpy.array2string`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html#numpy.array2string):

```
print(np.array2string(x, suppress_small=True))
```

To not use scientific notation by default for all printing, use [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions):

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```

As to *why* this happens - when printing a floating point array the default behaviour is to use scientific notation if:

- the minimum (absolute non zero) value to be printed is less than `0.0001`; or
- the ratio of the maximum (absolute non zero) value to minimum (absolute non zero) value is greater than `1000`.

This behaviour is suppressed if `suppress_small` is passed to `array2string` (or `suppress` to `set_printoptions`)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off scientific notation by changing numpy's print options:

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

syn0
>>> array([[-0.00083166],
           [ 0.45717134],
           [-0.58361112],
           [-0.50393288],
           [ 0.70334375],
           [-0.16830256],
           [ 0.23337013],
           [-0.53266772],
              ....
```